# How to dynamically set values of the properties C1, C2, ..., Cn in my class by their order numbers?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an SQL Server table that has a `bit` column for every day of the year going from 1 - 366.  I need to set the `bit` to 1 if the `dayofyear` is in the list for holidays or in the list for weekends. In my code, the column names were changed from [1]..[366] to [C1] .. [C366].

```
List<int> holidays = new List<int>();

List<int> weekends = ListWeekends(year);

HolidayRecords Hrecords = new HolidayRecords();
Hrecords.Program = Program;
Hrecords.Currency = Currency;

HolidayRecords.Add(db, Hrecords);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I will need to loop through all the columns and set them to `false` before I process each list, but not sure how to do that let alone loop through each list and set the corresponding column to `true`.

Comment: Have you considered running SQL directly?

Comment: I can't because the initial data comes in from a csv file that I have converted to a DataTable.  Each column in the Datatable represents a month and in the row there could be multiple days in quotes separated by a comma.

Comment: So that sounds like SQL with a `IN` clause?

Comment: I might be able to get away with a stored procedure, if that is what your referring to or LINQ.  Code?

Comment: Do you have safecode disabled? or does this have to be purely c# / sql

Comment: Needs to be c# / sql server.

Comment: Aside: It is more common to have a `Calendar` table in the database that has a _row_ for each date and additional columns to flag weekends, holidays, ... . The resulting table can be used in SQL `join` operations with other tables to conveniently handle various types of dates.

Comment: Yes that is a great idea when you have just one calendar, but I will need a 100+ copies of the calendar and each copy has different holidays.

Comment: for(int i = 1; i <= 366; i++){ Col ["C" + i.ToString()] = i;}

Comment: @Craig **1.** Does `HolidayRecords` is a class that has properties `C1`...`C366`? **2.** Do you want to loop through columns `C1`...`C366` and set their values to true if lists `holidays` or `weekends` contain an appropriate date? For example, if list `holidays` contains value `1` then `C1=true`. **3.** Where do exactly in the code you posted  you have a problem?

Comment: Why do you think you "need 100+ copies of the calendar"?

Comment: @Iliar Turdushev  HolidayRecords is a class that has properties Program, Currency and C1 ... C366.  I am going to default each of the Cx columns to false.  Then I need to loop through the two lists (holidays and weekends) and set the value to true if in the list.  I don't have code as I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Reflection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection) can be used to solve this problem. The next method uses `Reflection` to iterate through holidays and weekends and set appropriate `Cx` properties to true:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public static void FillHolidayRecords(HolidayRecords hr, List<int> holidays, List<int> weekends)
{ 
    Type type = hr.GetType();

    foreach (int day in holidays.Concat(weekends).Distinct())
    {
        // Get Cx property by day number.
        PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty($"C{day}");
        // Set value of the property to true.
        pi.SetValue(hr, true);
    }
}
```

In this method it is supposed that by default properties `Cx` equal to false.

---

> I will need to loop through all the columns and set them to False
>   before I process each list

If you declare each of the `Cx` properties as autoproperty without setting its values explicitly than values of these `Cx` properties will be `false`. And you will not need to set them to `false` in the loop.

```
public class HolidayRecords
{ 
    // By default if you don't set value of C1 in the constructor
    // its value is false.
    public bool C1 { get; set; }
    ...
}

public void Sample()
{
    HolidayRecords hr = new HolidayRecords();
    // Here the value of hr.C1 is false.
}
```